# Hadoop installation on Windows 10

Tags: windows, hadoop

I’m trying to install Hadoop 3.2.0 on Windows 10 using mostly the following tutorial:
https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows

I’ve found some relevant tutorial on the web even though they are principally related to Linux.

Every time I'm trying to verify the HDFS daemons are running with this code:
"%HADOOP_PREFIX%\bin\hdfs dfs -put myfile.txt /"
I constantly get the same error message: “Your endpoint configuration is wrong;”

I tried to change the port to 9000, change to localhost, also tried to use hostname:8820.

I checked Stack Overflow and Super User but I haven’t found already the answer.

What should I try?

Answer (score 0):

Try backslashes instead of forward slashes for windows paths